# Error with date time picker package flutter when pressing cancel on the picker

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am using the datetime_picker_formfield class and if i press cancel and try to reenter the prompt it does not let me, cancelling without a value also errors:

```dart
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:5399:30)
    at alerts.AddEventPopup.new.<anonymous> (http://localhost:50965/packages/fbla_lettering_point_app/Pages/Admin/settings.dart.lib.js:8642:115)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:50965/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

Here is the code:

```dart
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: DateTimeField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            fillColor: mainColor,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: "Date and Time",
                          ),
                          format: format,
                          controller: _dateController,
                          onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
                            ref.read(_dateDataProvider.state).state =
                                (await showDatePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    firstDate: DateTime(2021),
                                    initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                                    lastDate: DateTime(2100)))!;
                            if (ref.read(_dateDataProvider.state).state.day !=
                                null) {
                              ref.read(_timeDataProvider.state).state =
                                  (await showTimePicker(
                                context: context,
                                initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
                                    currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
                              )) as TimeOfDay;
                              return DateTimeField.combine(
                                  ref.read(_dateDataProvider.state).state,
                                  ref.read(_timeDataProvider.state).state);
                            } else {
                              return currentValue;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

What I do to get this error is when this is showing i press cancel without selecting all values needed. I want the user to select both date and time mandatory or cancel with no value. I also want the data to be shown in the box after filling it out so the user knows that they have filled it out.

Comment: what package you use for DateTimeField?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the null coalescing operator (`!`) applied to the result of `showDatePicker` and the cast to `TimeOfDay` of the `showTimePicker` result. Just check the result of them first if they are `null` like the following:

```
onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
  final date = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2021),
      initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100));
  if (date == null) return null;
  ref.read(_dateDataProvider.state).state = date;

  if (date.day != null) {
    final time = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime:
          TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
    );
    if (time == null) return null;
    ref.read(_timeDataProvider.state).state = time;
    return DateTimeField.combine(date, time);
  }

  return currentValue;
},
```